# Installing GDAL on CentOS?

Tags: gdal, installation, centos

I'm having issues with installing GDAL on a fresh install of Centos7 using the ELGIS repo. Here's my commands and output:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://elgis.argeo.org/repos/6/elgis-release-6-6_0.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y gdal
```

Here are the console errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libCharLS.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libdap.so.11()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libxerces-c-3.0.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libCharLS.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libfreexl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libxerces-c-3.0.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libgta.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libarmadillo.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libgta.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libfreexl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libdap.so.11()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libarmadillo.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: gpsbabel-1.4.4-1.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libshp.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-4.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
       Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
```

Is there another repo I need to install to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ELGIS [requires](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS#How_to_enable_the_ELGIS6_repository) EPEL (see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse for EPEL).

However I'm not sure that you really want to use ELGIS 6 on CentOS 7. Its intended for RHEL 6 / CentOS 6 / Scientific Linux 6.

Instead, you probably just want to use EPEL for CentOS 7 for something like GDAL. EPEL 7 has GDAL 1.11.0, which isn't quite the latest, but is certainly more current than the 1.9.2 that are you trying to install.

Comment: thanks for the response. this worked. GDAL is in the EPEL repo for CentOS so the ELGIS repo is not necessary.

Comment: It was enough to `yum install epel-release` and then `yum install gdal` in my case.

Comment: ```sudo yum deplist gdal | awk '/provider:/ {print $2}' | sort -u | sudo xargs yum -y install```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are new to EPEL, first you have to install EPEL. You can enable it for good, depens on you :)

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum install --enablerepo=epel gdal
```

If it is not regular yum repo, I search the internet "centos 7 'libraryname'" and if its on EPEL, the result usually poppes out. Or I visit EPEL repo and search here, usually their lib names are shortcuted. Also you can search the repo in the command line.

Comment: It works, but it installs a very old version of GDAL: GDAL 1.7.3, released 2010/11/10

Comment: haha, it is quite old Centos as well, check if new versons are supported...

Comment: It is the default Amazon Linux distribution, which should be based on a quite new version of CentOS.