# installing GDAL on cent os7 setup.py egg_info failed

Tags: python, gdal, centos

I saw this post here:

[Installing GDAL on CentOS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130324/install-gdal-on-centos-7)

And got the EPEL 7 installed, then did a `sudo yum install gdal` and it did its thing without errors.  However when trying to do a `sudo pip install gdal` I get the following error:

```
Collecting gdal
  Using cached GDAL-2.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xKfiOH/gdal/setup.py", line 320, in <module>
        **extra )
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 185, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 261, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 327, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 363, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 231, in add_defaults
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xKfiOH/gdal/setup.py", line 195, in finalize_options
        self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xKfiOH/gdal/setup.py", line 175, in get_gdal_config
        return fetch_config(option)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xKfiOH/gdal/setup.py", line 128, in fetch_config
        raise gdal_config_error, e""")
      File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
    __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xKfiOH/gdal/
```

No idea what this error is telling me (besides maybe it is a config file, btw easy_install gave me an error of this:

```
Searching for gdal
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/gdal/
Best match: GDAL 2.1.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/d1/98/27fff31ad298f3ec50db19dc3adfd8387279e158b1c6331c531c5fc7d830/GDAL-2.1.0.tar.gz#md5=64084a5f114b4dffc53280e28d2ba4f3
Processing GDAL-2.1.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-bFVEUq/GDAL-2.1.0/setup.cfg
Running GDAL-2.1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-bFVEUq/GDAL-2.1.0/egg-dist-tmp-MgCGUr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.9.8', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1992, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1979, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1996, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 380, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 653, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 849, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1130, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1115, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 69, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 120, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 320, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 177, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 185, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 261, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 327, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 363, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 231, in add_defaults
    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "setup.py", line 195, in finalize_options
  File "setup.py", line 175, in get_gdal_config
  File "setup.py", line 128, in fetch_config
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I haven gdal running on my mac just fine just when I try to install it on centos do I get these errors.  I am sure I am missing something no idea what.  My version of python on this server I am trying to get gdal on is 2.7.5 which I know is old not sure if that is a factor or not.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS 7: You will need two prerequisite packages before installing the GDAL pip package.

```
yum install gdal-devel gcc
```

Then you should have the required packages to install via pip

```
pip install GDAL
```

Answer (score 1):

I was finally successful after using these options, suggested by Arpad Horvath on stack overflow

sudo pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==1.10.0

works for centos 7 and ubuntu 16.