# Unable to install Python 3.4 gdal bindings on CentOS

Tags: python, gdal, installation, centos

I can easily install GDAL and Python bindings on a Windows machine, but I can not reproduce the same thing on a CentOS machine. The problem is I want to use Python 3.4 (Python 2.7 is too old and outdated for me). So, I have two versions of Python on my CentOS machine and if I do

```
# update-alternatives --config python
```

I see such a picture:

```
+ 1 /usr/bin/python2.7
* 2 /usr/bin/python3.4
```

So, Python 2.7 is now active and when I do this:

```
# yum install gdal-python
```

everything works ok, except one little fact - gdal is installed for Python 2.7. If however, I switch to Python 3.4 and run the same command, I see multiple errors in the console, like

```
 except OSError, e:     
 SyntaxError: invalid sytax
```

I do not know what to do with all this. What I want is just to be able to use gdal with Python 3.4.

Comment: What repo are you using? There's an [earlier question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130324/install-gdal-on-centos-7) that suggested  using EPEL rather than ELGIS, for instance. Also what's the CentOS version?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7.

Comment: I see that GDAL itself installed correctly - all those nice tools like gdalwarp, gdalinfo etc, are there and can be used. But the whole problem now is just in Python

Comment: I need to use gdal_retile.py and I need a bunch of modules from osgeo library, precisely, I need to do this - `from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr`. This works ok in Python 2.7. But I can not install (or I do not know how) to install gdal-python for Python 3.x

Comment: As for the repo, `yum list gdal-python` says, that I'm using `1.11.4-10.rhel7`. I do not even know if there is a repo for Python 3.X.

Comment: Is python venv / Docker an option for you (I'm not able to check on CentOS)? I tend to use [pygdal](https://github.com/dezhin/pygdal) as it plays nicely with venvs, but only ever tried this on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Steven Kay. Thanks! This idea to use Docker also crossed my mind.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways I have accomplished this using pip (if you do not have pip you must first do `yum install python3-pip`.

```
# using gdal package
yum install gdal-devel
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal  # path from `gdal-config --cflags`
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')

# using pygdal package
yum install gdal-devel
pip3 install pygdal="`gdal-config --version`.*"
```

Comment: I just used this successfully on CentOS 8.2. Keep in mind that you must also have the Python development headers: `python3-devel` installed.

Comment: No such luck. Still throws up all over itself :(